# Angular load data from server and publish in controllers

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want to grab some JSON Files with its content and make it available for other controllers. For this I know that I should create a factory that grabs the json files. My problem is that I dont know how to get the factory to return deityData.

Here is my Code that i want in a factory:

```
app.controller("dataContainer", function($scope,$http){

  $http.get("./data/deitys/data.json").then(function (response) {

    $scope.myData = response.data;
    for(var i = 0; i < $scope.myData["deitys"].length;i++){
        var dataString = "./data/deitys/" + $scope.myData["deitys"][i] +".json";

        $http.get(dataString).then(function (response_) {

            var deityData = response_.data;
            $scope.deitys[deityData.deityName] = deityData;
        });                                         
    }

});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Let's create a service for this, say **deityService**.

   ```
   angular.service("deityService", () => {
     this.deityData = undefined;
   });
   ```
2. In all those controllers who want that data, add **deityService** as a dependency.
3. When you are done fetching data in your *dataContainer* controller, set **deityData** like this and emit an event that will let all others know that data has been set.

   ```
   this.deityService.deityData = fetched_data;
   this.deityService.emit("DEITY_DATA_SET");
   ```
4. Add a listener to all those controller for event

   ```
   this.deityService.on("DEITY_DATA_SET",() => {
     // now you can do console.log(this.deityService.deityData);
     }
   );
   ```